# Issue while upgrading the azure aks cluster from 1.23.8 to 1.24.6 and getting error - CustomPrivateDNSZoneMissingPermissionError

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, pulumi-azure

I was trying to upgrade the AKS cluster using C#/Pulumi to upgrade the aks cluster version from 1.23.8 to 1.24.6. Getting below error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIEgK.png)

I have tried assigning PrivateDNSZonecontributor, contributor, Networkcontributor permissions for the aksmanaged identity. but no luck. Did any one got above issues? any suggesions/ideas to the resolutions appreciated.
Thanks, Praveen

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are granting the permissions to the wrong identity. You should grant the **cluster assigned identity** at least the Private DNS Zone Contributor and Network Contributor roles as [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters#configure-private-dns-zone).

To get the identity, use the ID found in the output of `az aks show -g <RG> -n <name> --query identity`

Comment: I have checked and found that i have assigned roles to aks cluster identity on but we have private links defined in various RGs across the sub, seems it is expecting to assign the read-write access for private links ( linked with private dns zones) . trying still issue not resolved yet.